# Dropdown menu using CSS not displaying the menu on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a dropdown menu to appear when the user hovers over the `About` menu, see http://jsfiddle.net/bpAbC/

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>
                <li>Three</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

nav > ul > li {
    display: table-cell;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

nav > ul > li a {
    color: red;
}

nav > ul > li > ul.sub {
    display: none;
}

nav > ul > li a:hover ul.sub {
    display: block;
}
```

The `.sub` ul is not displaying when I hover over About. I assume I have made an error with my last two rules but I can't work it out.

Comment: The UL is not a descendant element of `a`, so that rule does not match anything. Try `nav > ul > li a:hover ~ ul.sub, nav > ul > li ul.sub:hover` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change selector to `nav > ul > li:hover ul.sub` because `ul.sub` is not a child of `a`

```
nav > ul > li:hover ul.sub {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bpAbC/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
nav > ul > li:hover ul.sub {
    display: block;
}
```

And letme know if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Where you have

`nav > ul > li a:hover ul.sub {
    display: block;
}`

in your CSS, try

`nav > ul > li a:hover + ul.sub {
    display: block;
}`

The "+" between `a:hover` and `ul.sub` specifies that you want to select an [adjacent sibling](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) of the `<a>`. I think this is preferable because it is more specific about exactly which element you are selecting.

Comment: If you do that the sub menu will disappear as soon as you leave the link. Better to do li:hover